# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\strona\search.php on line 64

Tags: php

```
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($wynik))
      {
         echo "<tr>
               <td align=\"center\">".$line['id']."</td> 
               <td align=\"left\">".$line['imie']."</td>
               <td align=\"left\">".$line['imie_drugie']."</td>
               <td align=\"left\">".$line['nazwisko']."</td>
               <td align=\"center\">".$line['data_ur']."</td>
               <td align=\"center\">".$line['plec']."</td>
               <td align=\"center\">".$line['wiek']."</td>
               <td align=\"center\">".$line['knazwa']."</td>
               </tr>";
      }
```

Start line is 61. Last line is line 73.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Normally, I would just start commenting out code going backwards to see the exact place the error is, and you will have less to look at. Try commenting out the `id` line.

Comment: error is not in there

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` at the beginning of each line and `'` (single quotes) as start and end - then in the middle You can use `"` (double quotes).

Check this:

```
echo '<td align="center">'.$line['id'].'</td>';
```

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Then try to `print_r($line)` inside the `while` so see its content.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<tr>
         <td align='center'>".$line['id']."</td> 
         <td align='left'>".$line['imie']."</td>
         <td align='left'>".$line['imie_drugie']."</td>
         <td align='left'>".$line['nazwisko']."</td>
         <td align='center'>".$line['data_ur']."</td>
         <td align='center'>".$line['plec']."</td>
         <td align='center'>".$line['wiek']."</td>
         <td align='center'>".$line['knazwa']."</td>
       </tr>";
```